# SQL Query - finding multiple sums with a row

Tags: mysql, sql, jsp

I need some help trying to find out how I can make this SQL Query try and find the total sums for all unique BatchNo's

something like this:

```
|BatchNo| Sum |
    1     20
    2     45
    3     22
```

this is what i have right now.

```
SELECT BatchNo,
SUM(raw_bat_sum.STOTS + raw_bat_sum.STOTR)
AS Sum
FROM raw_bat_sum
WHERE raw_bat_sum.BatchNo= ?;
```

Comment: do you have sample data?

Comment: No `where`... just `GROUP BY batchNo` after the `FROM...`

Comment: you should be using GROUP BY on your query

Comment: thanks xQbert saved the day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT BatchNo,
(SUM(raw_bat_sum.STOTS) + SUM(raw_bat_sum.STOTR))
AS Sum
FROM raw_bat_sum
GROUP BY raw_bat_sum.BatchNo;
```

[EXAMPLE HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9aef16/1)